# Get position using XSLT (find all nodes after a particular item)

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I am trying to do a transformation like this.
Consider I am having a XML file :

```
 <name>
   <a>Andy</a>
   <b>Emma</b>
   <c>John</c>
   <d>Cindy</d>
   <e>May</e>
 </name>
```

And now I wish to select all elements after `<b>Emma</b>` element,so the output will be like this:

```
<new>
  <one>John</one>
  <one>Cindy</one>
  <one>May</one>
<new>
```

I can only done the condition by manually declare the condition as

`[position()>2]`

But is there any way to get the position automatically?Rough idea like this:

`[position()>Emma]` or `[position()>b]`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What you can do is `/name/*[. = 'Emma']/following-sibling::*` or `/name/b/following-sibling::*`.

Answer (score 3):

You needn't get the position,  you could use `[preceding-sibling::*[text() = 'Emma']]` or `[preceding-sibling::b]` instead.

Comment: Note that @Martin's solution should be much more efficient than this one.

Answer (score 2):

**Here is a complete transformation:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
     <new>
      <xsl:apply-templates select=
       "*[. = 'Emma']/following-sibling::*"/>
     </new>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*/*">
  <one><xsl:value-of select="."/></one>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<name>
    <a>Andy</a>
    <b>Emma</b>
    <c>John</c>
    <d>Cindy</d>
    <e>May</e>
</name>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<new>
   <one>John</one>
   <one>Cindy</one>
   <one>May</one>
</new>
```

**Another variation is to use the following match pattern**:

```
*/*[not('Emma' = .|following-sibling::*)]
```

**And the complete transformation now is**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
     <new>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
     </new>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*/*[not('Emma' = .|following-sibling::*)]">
  <one><xsl:value-of select="."/></one>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="*/*" priority="0"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: +1. Note that the two variants will return different results, if there is more than one `Emma` element.

Comment: @LarsH: Yes, As per the question this is assuming there is only one Emma. Thanks.